# How to make reference of generic interface containing classes?

Tags: c#, generics

I wanted to make a generic type parameter that reference any classes on my interface.  But it says there no implicit reference conversion between my `Model` and `Interface`. I can reference parameter type which is T to any class but I need to use all the classes inside interface. Any advice would appreciated. :)

```
interface IClassModel
{
    ClassOne MyFirstClass { get; set; }
    ClassTwo MySecondClass { get; set; }
}

class ClassOne
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

class ClassTwo
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void ProduceClass<T>() where T : IClassModel, new()
    {
        T value = new T();
        value.MyFirstClass.Num = 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProduceClass<ClassOne>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `ClassOne` in the context of `ProduceClass<T>`, since `T` must have a parameterless constructor and implement `IClassModel`.

Comment: `ClassOne` is not implementing `IClassModel` that's why you can not use it in `ProduceClass<ClassOne>();`

Comment: You need to put the Num property in the interface then your classes must implement the interface

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? for me this is still unclear. "but I need to use all the classes inside interface." What does that mean ?

Comment: What you did is completely nosense.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno to cite a famous [neurologist](http://forum.mit.edu/articles/what-neuroscience-can-teach-us-about-human-nature-and-the-potential-for-change/) "if it seems incomprehensible, that is usually because we are not smart enough to figure out what is going on in their brains"

Comment: if your model consits of 2 different objects, why do you try to create only one of them? is that you aim? you actually would like to have `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` under the same roof? so they should implement the same interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you wanted to do it this way:

```
interface IClassModel
{
    int Num { get; set; }
}

class ClassOne: IClassModel
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

class ClassTwo: IClassModel
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void ProduceClass<T>() where T : IClassModel, new()
    {
        T value = new T();
        value.Num = 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProduceClass<ClassOne>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem. But what if I made ClassOne as abstract and just inherit few getter and setter. It says <T> must be non abstract type.

Comment: abstract classes cannot be created by definition. If you made it abstract you can't create it, you can only create its non-abstract derivatives.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

Comment: From this article: An abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I see. Thanks for this. I just create a class that inherits abstract class.